# Переадресация, если пользователь ввошел. Laravel. PHP

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Я сделал просто с помощью js, но мне надо сделать так, чтобы не смогли никак обойти эту переадресацию ( с помощью консоли в браузере). В общем говоря, какие есть пути сделать переадресацию, если пользователь залогинился. Может в роутах прописать что-то?

```
@if (Route::has('login'))
@if (Auth::check())
<script>
    window.location.href = "<?php echo url('/home'); ?>";
</script>
@else
```

Comment: какая версия Laravel ?

Comment: @Arsen, 5.4, последняя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желательно  делать редирект через PHP, для Laravel можете использовать
`redirect()->intended('/');`
или 
`Redirect::intended('/');`

Comment: Как этим воспользоватся? В ларавеле новичок, ничего не ясно) Если, просто вставить `@if (Auth::check())
    <?php redirect()->intended('/home'); ?>
@els`, то не работает..

Comment: делайте просто if(Auth::check()){..... } else {....}

Answer (score 0):

**Можно использовать пример с официального сайта.**

```
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function()
{
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
}]);

// With A Controller...

Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@show']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы делали систему авторизации через команду `php artisan make:auth` то у вас должен был появиться среди прочих файл `LoginController.php`.

Полный путь к нему: `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`.

Так вот в нем достаточно поменять путь в этой строке:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Это путь, куда пользователь будет перенаправлен после успешной авторизации. Никаких JS тут не нужно городить.